# Call data from Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I am trying to write some code in php to show on a website exactly how many times a particular url has been tweeted on Twitter.

I assume I use the info in this page;
http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info?url=http://dori.co.nz/

But what code would I need to add to the header of a Wordpress theme to call those values?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp this would help u..

Comment: Thanks, I've read that but I just can't nail it. Here's what I have so far...

Comment: <?
$url = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info?url=http://dori.co.nz/";

$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$shares =  $xml->result->story->url_count;

echo $shares; 
?>

Comment: 'code' <?
$url = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info?url=http://dori.co.nz/";

$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$shares =  $xml->result->story->url_count;

echo $shares; 
?> '/code'

Comment: http://codepad.org/IP6gSBvZ  It makes sense to me for that to work, but it's calling errors back. starting to drive me a bit crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.tweetmeme.com/url_info?url=http://dori.co.nz/"; 
$test = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($test); 
echo $xml->story->url_count;
?>
```

Here we go.